# Lookup value directly from the matrix data

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

i have to data in two different sheet

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTUb9.jpg)

"Sheet1"

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkKSv.jpg)

"Sheet2"

In "Sheet3" i want to pull data from B2 "A" and get '74'

At present i use the below given formula for sheet1 & sheet2 respectively, to convert the matrix data to column data, and then use *index, match* could you please give a better solution

*=OFFSET($B$2:$E$5,MOD(ROW()-ROW($H$2),ROWS($B$2:$E$5)),TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($H$2))/ROWS($B$2:$E$5)),1,1)*

Note: the Data dosenot have any  Heading

Comment: where on the earth this 74 came from? Your question is not clear enough for us to guide you.Please re-frame the question with clear explanation on what you have and what you want..

Comment: Could you put a picture of the structure of Sheet3 as well? As is, your question is not entirely clear and it seems it could be done without even using Sheet1.

Comment: I know how it feels when you try SO interface for the first time. MS Excel is basically a programming tool and it is within the scope of our activity. But you need to tell us more precisely about your problem, otherwise we are unable to answer.

Comment: Also, there are `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` functions in Excel, have you tried?

Comment: Please go through the image fore the Sheets

"Sheet3"
[Sheet3](http://i.imgur.com/303bDzP.jpg)

Comment: it keeps showning you need points to post stuff

Comment: in the image for sheet3 A-P is given in order, it could be also jumbled

Comment: @Stephinn, it's `VLOOKUP` in your case, see my answer.

Comment: the data are in 2 different sheet and i have to get the result in a different sheet

Comment: So the required results are precisely the values which occupy the same cell address in Sheet2 as that for each of the terms being searched in Sheet1?

Comment: yes thats the whats required @XORLX

Comment: Are you using Excel 2010 or later?

Comment: EXCEL 2010 is what i use

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me try to answer prematurely. It is not clear yet (unless you edit it) from your question what exactly your problem is, but I can suggest some helpful spreadsheet functions for these situations:

```
HLOOKUP( search_criteria, array, index, sorted )
VLOOKUP( search_criteria, array, index, sorted )
```

These perform respectively horizontal and vertical lookup by the values in the first row / column.

```
OFFSET( reference, rows, columns, height, width )
```

Returns you a cell relative (shifted) from the reference cell by a specified number of rows and columns. With this, `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions might come handy. Finally, there is this function

```
INDIRECT( string_reference )
```

which is the jackhammer to allow you to construct a reference as a string to get you out of any tricky kind of situations. Usually, however, the functions I mentioned earlier will help you with whatever you need.

For example, if you have a table

```
A     42
B     43
C     44
D     45
```

starting from the cell `A1`, function `=VLOOKUP( "B", A1:B4, 2, 0 )` will return 43.

Comment: the data are in 2 different sheets

Comment: the calculation is in SHEET3, the data is in SHEET1 and the Refrence is in SHEET2.

Comment: Stephinn, my goodness, and you don't know how to refer to other sheets in spreadsheets? Are you sure you read the user manual? Instead of `A1:B4`, write `Sheet1!A1:B4`, that's it. You can use mouse, too, and the spreadsheet will fill the reference for you by itself. It's really easy, you just need more practice.